# how to avoid extra spacing in template while using if endif condition in template django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i am retrieving information from the database and using {%if%} and {%endif%} condition so if that field is blank it does not cause any problem but when that field does not have any value it creates a new blank line in place of that looks bad in styling I saw an answer use this {%if -%} {%- endif %}it doesn't work and throws the error all I want if field is blank do not create any new blank line and render second line below that without creating any whitespace
any suggestion will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could format like this:

```html
My first line{% if second_line %}<br>
{{second_line}}{% endif %}<br>
My third line
```

The idea being if `second_line` doesn't exist it won't render that `<br>`

Comment: i am also using br tag outside endif that causing the new line

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in templatetag

```
{% spaceless %}
    Space less content here
{% endspaceless %}
```

As per the documentation that can be found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless

The`spaceless` tag:

> Removes whitespace between HTML tags. This includes tab characters and newlines.

```
{% spaceless %}
    <p>
        <a href="foo/">Foo</a>
    </p>
{% endspaceless %}
```

Would result in:

```
<p><a href="foo/">Foo</a></p>
```

Comment: will that output as: `Spacelesscontenthere`?- or does it just like a `.strip()` call?

Comment: Please see my updated answer, it is likely the correct one as per your question, but that is at your discretion. Very difficult to say without seeing your code or html